# D3.js: Text labels dissapear when I click on the second svg element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization, bubble-chart

I am new to D3.js and trying to make a visualization in which I am facing a problem wherein, I have two Bubble Charts in my display as two separate SVG elements, as shown below:

[SVG Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhBGq.png)

Now, the problem is that when I click on one of the SVG elements, the text labels from the second disappear  and vice-versa, as shown:
[On Clicking one of the charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB8WN.png)

and: 
[When I click on the SVG as well, it disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuFcm.png)

The code for the above is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var svg = d3.select("#svg1"),
                margin = 20,
                diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
                g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

            var color = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([-1, 5])
                .range(["hsl(200,80%,80%)", "hsl(128,30%,90%)"])
                .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

            var pack = d3.pack()
                .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
                .padding(2);

            d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
              if (error) throw error;

              root = d3.hierarchy(root)
                  .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
                  .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

              var focus = root,
                  nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
                  view;

              var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
                  .style("fill", function(d,i) { 
                    console.log(d.data.name);
                    return d.data.color ? d.data.color : "ff99bb"; })
                  .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

              var text = g.selectAll("text")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("text")
                  .attr("class", "label")
                  .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
                  .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
                  .style("font-size", function(d){ return d.parent === root ? "12px" : "24px";})
                      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

              var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

              svg
                  .style("background", "#ffffff ") // change color of the square
                  .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

              zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

              function zoom(d) {
                var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

                var transition = d3.transition()
                    .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                    .tween("zoom", function(d) {
                      var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
                      return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
                    });

                transition.selectAll("text")
                  .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
                    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
                    .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
                    .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
              }

              function zoomTo(v) {
                var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
                node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
                circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
              }
            });


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////SVG2///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                var svg2 = d3.select("#svg2"),
                    margin2 = 20,
                    diameter2 = +svg2.attr("width"),
                    g2 = svg2.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter2 / 2 + "," + diameter2 / 2 + ")");



                    var color2 = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([-1, 5])
                    .range(["hsl(200,80%,80%)", "hsl(128,30%,90%)"])
                    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

                var pack2 = d3.pack()
                    .size([diameter2 - margin2, diameter2 - margin2])
                    .padding(2);

                d3.json("flare2.json", function(error, root2) {
                  if (error) throw error;

                  root2 = d3.hierarchy(root2)
                      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
                      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

                  var focus2 = root2,
                      nodes2 = pack(root2).descendants(),
                      view;

                  var circle2 = g2.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(nodes2)
                    .enter().append("circle")
                      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
                      .style("fill", function(d,i) { 
                        console.log(d.data.name);
                            return d.data.color ? d.data.color : "#ddccff "; })
                      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

                  var text2 = g2.selectAll("text")
                    .data(nodes2)
                    .enter().append("text")
                      .attr("class", "label2")
                      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root2 ? 1 : 0; })
                      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root2 ? "inline" : "none"; })
                      .style("font-size", function(d){ return d.parent === root2 ? "12px" : "24px";})
                          .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

                  var node2 = g2.selectAll("circle,text");

                  svg2
                      .style("background", "#ffffff ") // change color of the square
                      .on("click", function() { zoom(root2); });

                  zoomTo([root2.x, root2.y, root2.r * 2 + margin2]);

                  function zoom(d) {
                    var focus1 = focus; focus = d;

                    var transition2 = d3.transition()
                        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
                          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin2]);
                          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
                        });

                    transition2.selectAll("text")
                      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
                        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
                        .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
                        .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
                  }

                  function zoomTo(v) {
                    var k = diameter2 / v[2]; view = v;
                    node2.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
                    circle2.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
                  }
                });
</script>
```

What mistake am I doing in this?
Can someone please help me how to make it correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dcluo is right that the issue is with the line noted, but the reason is that the following code

```
transition.selectAll("text")
   .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
    .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
    .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
```

and the corresponding code in the second svg isn't selective enough.

if you would change the

```
selectAll("text")
```

to

```
selectAll("text.label")
```

in the first svg zoom method and

```
selectAll("text.label2")
```

in the second svg zoom method

that would only change the opacity in only the nodes for the respective svg containers.

selectAll is just like any other javascript selection method like jQuery's $('input') or plain javascript document.getElementsByTagName("UL").
text is actually a tag name and there is no context passed when it runs to know that it should only run in the parent svg.

Take a look at https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/

Comment: Hey Jose! Thanks for replying back! It totally works! Thanks for the answer! Just for some advice to a novie d3 learner, how do you reckon I should debug d3.js code? I just cant seem to grasp it.

Comment: d3 is javascript and you can debug it like any other js.  open your developer console and set a breakpoint.  One think I like to do is set styles on elements so I can more clearly see the extent of selections.  For example, here, I would do something like:  d3.selectAll('text').attr('style', 'fill: green')

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
.style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
```

is responsible for this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for replying back! Can you kindly tell me how do I make this right?

Comment: Hi Krittt, if you do not wish the label to disappear at all, have you tried remove these lines?

Comment: Thanks for replying back. But even after removing these lines, the text labels disappear. I am still as clueless. Please tell me what to do to fix this. Thanks in advance!